# How to debug(make page look like in Firefox) CSS in IE?

Tags: css, debugging, internet-explorer, firebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools Debugging CSS in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145335/tools-debugging-css-in-internet-explorer)

I know there is debugbar plugin, but its not free. How do you debug CSS in IE? I tried firebug lite, but I did not like it. Are there any other free and powerful tools?

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145335/tools-debugging-css-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try installing IETester which has it's own debugbar. http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in debugger if you're on IE8.
If you're on IE7 you can download the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) from Microsoft.

Comment: the built in debugger on IE8 works very well, especially since you can see how your code looks in other versions of IE.